# What does "tee: stdout: Broken pipe" during RVM ruby install mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

While doing a clean install of Ruby via RVM,

```
rvm remove all

rvm install ruby
```

I saw several lines of the following in my installation output:

```
tee: stdout: Broken pipe
tee: stdout: Broken pipe
tee: stdout: Broken pipe
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You should open a bug: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: can you please try rvm install 2.0.0